# Browse LDAP strcuture using Solaris pre-packaged command?

Tags: solaris, ldap

I have used [ldapsearch](http://www.opensolarisforum.org/man/man1/ldapsearch.html) to pull details on accounts but is there a way to browse the different levels in the LDAP directory just like we do with files in a directory?

Comment: Please clarify what you expect. i.e. "just like we do with files in a directory" with what command ? What limitation do you believe ldapsearch has ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, and no.  There is no pre-packaged tool that "comes with" Solaris, that serves as an LDAP browser.  You could do an big giant wild-card `ldapsearch`, and just read through from end to end using `less`.

However, if you have Solaris LDAP servers, then there's a possibility that the Solaris (Sun or Oracle) Directory Service Control Center (DSCC) is installed.  This is a web based system based on Apache/Tomcat that centralizes the management of LDAP servers in a Solaris environment.  See: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19261-01/820-2763/6nebgu69u/index.html

The DSCC does include LDAP browsers, as well as a convenient way to manage server settings, replication settings, etc, etc. And, it is a packaged product from Oracle, and as such may be allowed in your environment.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gqclient/) is what you are looking for.

Maybe there is a solaris version out there…,
another one, but webbased could be [this](http://phpldapadmin.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Thanks! But I am looking for a way to browse using a pre-packaged command.. Basically I work in an environment where there are restrictions to using outside apps